# set value to 2nd td (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I'm making a table adding some td to rows like this way:

```
...
switch( nieto.columnas[k].tipocampo ){
    case 'date':
    var ad_date = <Date ref={bisnieto.ref} value={"31-12-2016"} error={bisnieto.error} _ref={i + "-" + j + "-" + rowk + '-' + k} onChangeValue={onChangeValue} />;
    tr.push(
        <td className={"td-margin uk-width-medium-1-"+ columsCount} key={'table-input'+i+"-"+j+'-'+rowk+'-'+k} >
            {ad_date}
        </td>
    );
    break;
    ...
```

I'm adding multiple td to some rows, but I need that only the 2nd td has the value={"31-12-2016"} the rest need to have the value: value={bisnieto.value}. I was doing something like:

```
    case 'fecha':
    if (j==2) var ad_date= <Date ref={bisnieto.ref} value={"31-12-2016"} error={bisnieto.error} _ref={i + "-" + j + "-" + rowk + '-' + k} onChangeValue={onChangeValue} />;
    else var ad_date= <Date ref={bisnieto.ref} value={bisnieto.value} error={bisnieto.error} _ref={i + "-" + j + "-" + rowk + '-' + k} onChangeValue={onChangeValue} />;
    tr.push(
        <td className={"td-margin uk-width-medium-1-"+ columsCount} key={'table-input'+i+"-"+j+'-'+rowk+'-'+k} >
            {ad_date}
        </td>
    );
```

But I can't know when j will actually == 2, so don't consider i,j,row,rowk for that condition. I'm trying to use td:nth-child(2) like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/68wbx/1/ but don't how to do it in Reactjs.

Comment: provide some sample data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking "j === 2", you could check if "tr.length === 1". If the row already has one td in it, you're obviously about to add the 2nd one.